# Alert when element id is in viewport with jquery appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, viewport

Can't get this plugin to work for me: https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear

Using Ajax to refer to plugin from this CDN: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.3/jquery.appear.js

What am I doing wrong? I want an alert when div id #footer is in viewport.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.3/jquery.appear.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function() {
    $("#footer").appear(function() {
            alert('I see a footer!');
        });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [demo page](http://morr.github.io/appear.html) of the plugin I achieved to make it work.

1. First make the footer element able to fire **'appear'** event when it becomes visible on the viewport:

   ```
   $("#footer").appear();
   ```
2. Then listen for the event like this:

   ```
   $("body").on("appear", "#footer", function() {
       // Do something...
   });
   ```

**Code snippet:**

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.3/jquery.appear.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function() {
    $("#footer").appear();

    $("body").on("appear", "#footer", function() {
      alert('I see a footer!');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 300px">Scroll down</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```